# opencv show rendered image with bounding boxes and labels

Tags: python, opencv

The code below is able to detect objects without issue, however, towards the end there is the line "cv2.imshow("demo", img)"

I would expect this window to show the image with the generated bounding boxes and labels, but all I get is a blank window. I got this code originally from some examples on the internet so I'm a bit lost as to how to position that line, or why it's not generating the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def take_pic(output_filename):
    import os
    capture_img="ffmpeg -y -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://mycamera:apassword@172.16.66.106/live -vframes 1 " + output_filename



net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "./darknet/cfg/yolov3.cfg")
classes = []
with open("./darknet/data/coco.names", "r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))



output_filename = "/tmp/camera.jpeg"
cap = cv2.imread(output_filename)
j = 0




if j==0:
        cv2.namedWindow("demo", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

        while True:
                take_pic(output_filename)
                cap = cv2.imread(source)
                j = j + 1
                print("j= " + str(j))
                img = cap
                img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
                height, width, channels = img.shape

                blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
                net.setInput(blob)
                outs = net.forward(output_layers)

                class_ids = []
                confidences = []
                boxes = []
                for out in outs:
                    for detection in out:
                        scores = detection[5:]
                        class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                        confidence = scores[class_id]
                        if confidence > 0.5:
                            # Object detected
                            center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                            center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                            print(str(center_x)+" "+str(center_y))
                            w = int(detection[2] * width)
                            h = int(detection[3] * height)
                            # Rectangle coordinates
                            x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                            y = int(center_y - h / 2)
                            boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                            confidences.append(float(confidence))
                            class_ids.append(class_id)

                            indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4)

                            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
                            for i in range(len(boxes)):
                                if i in indexes:
                                    x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
                                    label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
                                    print("label :"+str(label)+"x: "+str(x)+" y: " + str(y))
                                    color = colors[i]
                                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
                                    cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y + 30), font, 3, color, 3)
                cv2.imshow("demo", img)

        else:
            print("camera open failed")

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

With opencv, a `imshow` is required to be accompanied with a `waitKey` method in order to display an image.

Paste something similar to this towards the end of your loop, after you call `cv2.imshow`:

```py
if cv2.waitKey(0) == ord('q'):
    print('exitting loop')
    break
```

Comment: I noticed that when I added your code it works, however, I have to press the space bar, or any key to get the next frame to get captured again, looks like the waitkey is causing the program to stall

Comment: @SarahCharnette `cv2.waitKey(0)` was an example. I didn't realize you wanted to play it continuously. Set it to `1` or any other positive int. The argument represents the wait time in milliseconds, but `0` means to wait indefinitely

Comment: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#:~:text=cv2.waitKey%28%29%20is%20a%20keyboard%20binding%20function.%20Its%20argument,passed%2C%20it%20waits%20indefinitely%20for%20a%20key%20stroke.

Answer (score 0):

If the image shows blank during `imshow` method, then you might need to multiply pixels with 255. For instance, in Matlab, the images are normalized between 0 - 1.

Try:

```
cv2.imshow("demo", img * 255)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I have to press the space bar, or any key to get the next frame to get captured again, looks like the waitkey is causing the program to stall

Comment: @SarahCharnette try `cv2.waitKey(1)`